# Python calculate mean values of specific key in a nested dictionary (IBM Watson Speech to Text API results)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, ibm-watson

I am comparing baseline confidence for IBM Watson text to speech across several audio files. I can access the confidence level of a single record using `pprint(data_response['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['confidence'])` but can't return multiple confidence levels. I need to calculate the mean confidence level of the entire transcript. I've looked into iterating over the nested dict, but everywhere I've read so far says that only returns the keys and not the values.

What method should be used to get a mean of all confidence levels?

Here is what the nested dictionary looks like using pretty print:

```
{'result_index': 0,
 'results': [{'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.99, 'transcript': 'hello '}],
              'final': True},
             {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.9,
                                'transcript': 'good morning any this is '}],
              'final': True},
             {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.59,
                                'transcript': "I'm on a recorded morning "
                                              '%HESITATION today start running '
                                              "yeah it's really good how are "
                                              "you %HESITATION it's one three "
                                              'six thank you so much for '
                                              'asking '}],
              'final': True},
             {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.87,
                                'transcript': 'I appreciate this opportunity '
                                              'to get together with you and '
                                              '%HESITATION you know learn more '
                                              'about you your interest in '}],
              'final': True},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `statistics.mean` to calculate the mean of all confidence levels:

```py
from statistics import mean

data_response = {
    "result_index": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "alternatives": [{"confidence": 0.99, "transcript": "hello "}],
            "final": True,
        },
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {"confidence": 0.9, "transcript": "good morning any this is "}
            ],
            "final": True,
        },
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "confidence": 0.59,
                    "transcript": "I'm on a recorded morning "
                    "%HESITATION today start running "
                    "yeah it's really good how are "
                    "you %HESITATION it's one three "
                    "six thank you so much for "
                    "asking ",
                }
            ],
            "final": True,
        },
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "confidence": 0.87,
                    "transcript": "I appreciate this opportunity "
                    "to get together with you and "
                    "%HESITATION you know learn more "
                    "about you your interest in ",
                }
            ],
            "final": True,
        },
    ],
}

m = mean(
    a["confidence"] for r in data_response["results"] for a in r["alternatives"]
)
print(m)
```

Prints:

```
0.8375
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! It worked perfectly on the larger dictionary. Is this list comprehension?

Comment: @JeremyToepp It's actually generator-comprehension, but it's similar.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I didn't know that it existed. I've got Fluent Python by Luciano Ramahlo as my main desk book for python, and it mentions that generator expression is lazy while list comprehension is eager. Does that mean that generator comprehension is more efficient?

Comment: @JeremyToepp With list-comprehension you first create a list and then pass this list to `mean()`. Generator-comprehension skip the list-creating step.